# Conflict between jqueries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-easyui

hi I want to use EasyUI GridView and Tab in Asp.net MVC4 and I put two Grid in a Tab.
but I have problem with it.
I added these Script and css in My Layout:

```
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.blueopal.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.rtl.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/1-ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/2-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/3-ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/jquery.min.js")"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.all.min.js")"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"> </script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"> </script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc.js"> </script>
<script src="~/Scripts/calendar.js"> </script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc-fa.js"> </script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"> </script>
```

and I added in My Index these :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/MapScript/Sld.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MapScript/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAl9RMqSzhPUXAfeBCXOussRSPP9rEdPLw3W8siaiuHC3ED5y09RTJKbutSNVCYFKU-GnzKsHwbJ3SUw'></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MapScript/ToolsMenu.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/MapStyle/MStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="~/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MapScript/LoadMap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/mootools-core-1.4-full.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/mootools-more-1.4-full.js"></script>
```

and in My page that I want to load EasyUI GridView I added these:

```
 <link href="~/Scripts/easyui-1.3.6/themes/icon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/easyui-1.3.6/themes/default/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/easyui-1.3.6/themes/default/easyui-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but when I Load My page, first the Tab is not loaded and with reClick on its Link , it loaded.

I think it for conflicting between jqueries that added?????!!!

note: when I create this page without index and Layout ,there isn't no problem

what is the problem??

Comment: well you have at least 3 different jquery includes on your page and a lot of other crap. Why? And what is the console error if you get any?

Comment: the console doesn't show error.My Project is big, one of My page is this . I have written My project with Kendo and now I want replace the grid kendo with EasyUI GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.noConflict()` in order to avoid conflict between different js files.

see here :- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

NOTE :- Try including required js and css files at one place.

Answer (score 0):

Load Mootools before jQuery. Then, use either

```
document.id("id_of_element")
```

or enclose any Mootools classes in

```
( function () {
    $ = document.id;
    this.MyClass = new Class({
    ...
    });
 })();
```

This will solve any conflicts between jQuery and MooTools, at least.